# How to replace whole cell in pandas, with values from other dataframe and rest to be set as 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two DataFrames.
df1:

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
25zx | b(50gh) |         |
50tr | a(70lc) | c(50gh) |
```

df2:

```
  A  |  B
-----|-----
  b  | 1.2
  a  | 3.5
  c  |  6
```

I want to replace values in df1. The row that I'm comparing is df2['A'], but the value that I want to put in to df1 is value from the row df['B']. Note my goal is for new value to replace whole cell, and cells that don't have anything to replace to set as 1.

So the final table would look like:

df3:

```
A    |    B    |    C
-----|---------|---------|
  1  |   1.2   |    1    |
  1  |   3.5   |    6    |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `regex` with `replace` then `apply` `to_numeric` follow by `fillna`

```
df3 = df1.replace(df2.set_index('A').B,regex=True)
df3 = df3.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(1)
df3
Out[123]: 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  1.2  1.0
1  1.0  3.5  6.0
```